# Error: failed to connect to database: password authentication failed in Rust

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

I am trying to connect to database in Rust using `sqlx` crate and Postgres database.

`main.rs`:

```
use dotenv;
use sqlx::Pool;
use sqlx::PgPool;
use sqlx::query;

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    dotenv::dotenv().ok();
    pretty_env_logger::init();
    let url = std::env::var("DATABASE_URL").unwrap();
    dbg!(url);

    let db_url = std::env::var("DATABASE_URL")?;
    let db_pool: PgPool = Pool::new(&db_url).await?;

    let rows = query!("select 1 as one").fetch_one(&db_pool).await?;
    dbg!(rows);

    let mut app = tide::new();
    app.at("/").get(|_| async move {Ok("Hello Rustacean!")});
    app.listen("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;

    Ok(())
}

#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug)]
enum Error {
    #[error(transparent)]
    DbError(#[from] sqlx::Error),

    #[error(transparent)]
    IoError(#[from] std::io::Error),

    #[error(transparent)]
    VarError(#[from] std::env::VarError),
}
```

Here is my `.env` file:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost/twitter
RUST_LOG=trace
```

Error log:

```
error: failed to connect to database: password authentication failed for user "ayman"
  --> src/main.rs:19:16
   |
19 |     let rows = query!("select 1 as one").fetch_one(&db_pool).await?;
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `backend`.
```

Note:

1. There exists a database called `twitter`.
2. I have include `macros` for sqlx's dependency

```
sqlx = {version="0.3.5", features = ["runtime-async-std", "macros", "chrono", "json", "postgres", "uuid"]}
```

Am I missing some level of authentication for connecting to database? I could not find it in docs for `sqlx::Query` [macro](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.3.5/sqlx/macro.query.html)

Answer (score 5):

The reason why it is unable to authenticate is that you must provide credentials before accessing the database

There are two ways to do it

**Option 1:** Change your URL to contain the credentials - For instance -

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost?dbname=mydb&user=postgres&password=postgres
```

**Option 2** Use PgConnectionOptions  - For instance

```
let pool_options = PgConnectOptions::new()
        .host("localhost")
        .port(5432)
        .username("dbuser")
        .database("dbtest")
        .password("dbpassword");

    let pool: PgPool = Pool::<Postgres>::connect_with(pool_options).await?;
```

**Note:** The sqlx version that I am using is **sqlx = {version="0.5.1"}**

For more information refer the docs - https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.5.1/sqlx/postgres/struct.PgConnectOptions.html#method.password

Hope this helps you.